# Change the submit function for user login

Tags: users

I'm building a site for a client that already has a website through another CMS that they do not wish to move away from despite my best efforts to convince them otherwise.

This CMS does offer an api that allows for implementation for single sign on so I'm trying to set that up.

I've gotten as far as

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
    {
        if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
            $form['#submit'] = ['mymodule_login'];
        }
    }

    function mymodule_login($form, &$form_state)
    {
        exit('SUCCESS');
    }
```

But the success message is never shown.

Oh, I tried searching to see if there was already a module that implemented this but no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was inputting an incorrect username and password and it was not reaching any of the submit hooks because it was failing on the validate hooks. It seems that my logic needs to go there if it wants to supercede the default validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Is you module named mymodule? The prefix of the hooks has to be the same as the machine readable name of your module. After checking that, try clearing the cache. After that, is should work because the code looks all right.

Comment: It's not called mymodule but it was a simple search and replace to produce the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`user_external_login_register`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7.x)

> Helper function for authentication modules. Either logs in or
>   registers the current user, based on username. Either way, the global
>   $user object is populated and login tasks are performed.

There is a good comment there about how to implement that type of external login flow. https://api.drupal.org/comment/13434#comment-13434